# How to stop Clang from spewing hundreds of messages about candidates?

Tags: c++, compiler-errors

When my source code has an error such a misspelled function or class name, has the or wrong argument types, the clang compiler likes to list all the candidates that might work instead.  I can also get "candidate function not viable" and " candidate template ignored: could not match" messages.

With templates and STL, and many large complex libraries involved in the project, sometimes clang spews a zillion lines like that.  I don't want to see any of them; they're not useful.

Is there a command line option to turn off this feature?

And what about g++?

Answer (score 0):

What about move clang and gcc to clang.bin and gcc.bin,
and replace them with such script:

```
#!/bin/sh

path/to/clang.bin $@ 2>&1 | head -n 100
```

that show only 100 lines of clang output